# Send list from HTML to TypeScript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I do have in my HTML a [`mat-table`](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) as a row in other `mat-table`:

```
 <mat-table [dataSource]="items"> 

    <mat-table [dataSource]="row.rowItems"> </mat-table>

</mat-table>
```

`row.rowItems` `dataSource` is **not** bound to a list in TypeScript, since I derived it from my HTML.

How can I access `[dataSource]="row.rowItems"` in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access specific row in .TS file as follows,

if you want to sselect 3rd row you can do following.

```
this.dataSource.data[2];
```

Comment: in TypeScript is not seen as a dataSource. Is not seen at all. This is what i want